# Which color scheme is used in jsFiddle and is there one for Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext, jsfiddle, color-scheme

The Color scheme used in jsFiddle is beautiful, but I can't find the same one as that for Sublime Text. I'm trying find it in Colorsublime.com, but unsuccessfully.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Another site to check is [tmTheme Editor](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Neon). To see all the light-colored themes, click `Gallery` in the upper left, then `Light`. Unfortunately, due to the way the app is written, what is displayed on the web page isn't exactly what you'll see in Sublime, but it's a fairly good representation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the TwoStones color scheme which is available in Sublime ColorScheme UI